# like others i cant get fragment down to less than 7%

Tags: defragment

i now use Piriform CCLEANER PRO to clear out all internet temp files & cache etc every time i close my browser(daily)  and i use Piriform CCLEANER PRO to clear out my registry. (twice a week)
i also got Piriform's DEFLAGGER which is better than windows defrag. I still get 7% after running the new DEFLAGGER THREE TIMES .  it also says the 7% is 112 fragmented files and of those files there 359total fragmentst, totaling 5.8gb in size (7%) .

- other info: im on older pc with windows 10 home premium and my hard drive has 85% free , i got plenty of free space its a HP Pavilion DV6 Notebook PC with 4G/RAM.
  Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU M 370  @ 2.40GHz   2.40 GHz

H E L P ? PLEASE?

Comment: The files are probably system files that are in use. The main question would be: does it actually matter? Files being fragmented isn't the end of the world and will be an insignificant part of the delays in reading a file and probably are not slowing your system down at all. Is there a reason you need this? What is the actual problem beyond a few fragmented files, which is quite a normal part of using a computer.

Comment: well it does slow me down a lil  .  im on older pc 4 g ram .  but i understand what your saying.  its older , i should chill run the defrag less and dont worry abvout it?  thank you

Comment: Yes, unless you are willing to go to extremes such as pulling the drive out and putting it in an external HDD enclosure to defrag on another machine or [running up a copy of Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59007/defragging-ntfs-partitions-from-linux) then the hours wasted are likely to be far more than the milliseconds it takes the OS to deal with a fragmented file. A far more useful thing to spend time on would be upgrading to an SSD (where fragmentation is basically irrelevant) and you'd potentially get a decent and more worthwhile performance boost too.